# Can't get crontab to work as expected

Tags: 20.04, cron, mta

I want to do a daily backup of my home directory by executing the following script (I can write to /home):

```
   #!/bin/sh -e
   cd /home
   ls -l 
   rm -f silbar.tar.gz
   echo "starting tar"
   tar -czf silbar.tar.gz silbar
   cd ./silbar
   echo "done with tar"
   beep
```

To do so I created my personal crontab file by enter ~$ crontab -e and added the following (and only line which is not a comment)

```
30 6 * * * mybackup.script
```

assuming that my crontab would run in my home directory.

But nothing happens.  Doing  ~$ grep CRON /var/log/syslog  shows, apart from root things, the following error:

Aug 30 06:30:01 Puma CRON[100126]: (silbar) CMD (mybackup.script )

Aug 30 06:30:01 Puma CRON[100125]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

So, what am I doing wrong?  What is MTA, anyway?

Comment: Your script has an error. We don't know what the error is. Cron is attempting to e-mail you the error message, but your system isn't set up for that. Instead of mucking about setting up an MTA for cron, simply redirect the error output to a file so you can read it.

Comment: Example: `30 6 * * * /home/silbar/mybackup.script > /home/silbar/backup.log 2>&1`

Comment: please do not use /home for personal files. The only thing in there should be user directories. Put them elsewhere; also never put more than 1 home in tar file; use 1 file per /home/USER/ and put it in /home/USER (consider it "better practice"). It is a confidentiality breach if you don't. And always use absolutes paths when using cron. It is the safest method. The "rm" is not needed. "tar" by default overwrites without asking.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to enter the full path of your script in your cronjob.

Cronjobs run with an almost empty environment. Thus, executables may not be found. The same goes for the commands in the script: provide full paths to commands, or set up a PATH variable in your script.

Answer (score 0):

By beginning with `#!/bin/sh -e`, you cause your script to run with `sh` (`bash`is better IMHO), and `-e` exits on any error (`man set`), so one cannot handle errors. Your script is failing, and `cron` is trying to email you the log. `cron` can't find a Message Transfer Agent (MTA). Email hasn't been configured on your system, even for local delivery.

Jobs run through `cron`, or `systemd` startup scripts aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. `systemd` startup scripts are run as `root`. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Answer (score 0):

Wow!, very useful answers from user535733, Rinzwind, Vanadium, and waltinator.  I now have it working as suggested, using bash and full paths.  The backup now goes to a flash drive (which is where I wanted it to go, anyway) instead of to /home.

Thanks to all, Dick